# Descrese quantity when order is placed

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to decrement quantity 10 of particular product each time place an order by customer in magento. its don't matter what quantity added in product detail page by customer.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using observer like sales_quote_add_item, will allow you to set custom quantity once the product is added to the cart.